# html5: css styling: <ul> <li> vs <p> for column of links

Tags: css, html, html-lists, semantics

There are 4 columns of links in the footer each of 25% of width. 
The css style of each column is the same (they belong to the same class).
The first column looks like:

**Title of Column 1**

link11

link12

link13

I think it is possible to use  `<ul><li>` tags or `<p>` tags to reach the goal. Which way is better, using `<ul>, <li>`  or `<p>`?

**Added to the question:**
P.S.I've just checked the link http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_nav.asp , they use `<!DOCTYPE html>` (as I understand, html5), but if you check how they wrap the column of linke (my question), they just use `<br/>` instead of `<p>` or `<li>` (see the view source of the left column).
Is using `<br/>` even better than `<ul><li>` or `<p>`?

Comment: "Is using <br/> even better than <ul><li> or <p>?" - Absolutely positively not.

Comment: I agree with @MrMisterMan with either ``<ul><li>`` or ``<p>`` you at least have a tag that you can stylize with css.

Comment: BR is a line-breaking tag and not a container element describing the contents. You "can" use it to make the code smaller. But you'll be ignoring semantics while you're at it. In the end, most people won't care... but (for example) the people with disabilities that stumble over your website will be missing a "list of links" and could run into trouble trying to understand a long paragraph full of links, only separated with short pauses (line-breaks). To them, and to semantic search engines, something like that is just a paragraph with no usefull content except a bunch of links. I would avoid it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it semantically correct, you would write the html according to your content. As you are displaying "a list of links", an "ul" is the way to go.

And (as a bonus) if you want to make it HTML5 compliant while you're at it, wrap the list in a "nav" tag.

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: The footer element alone is sufficient for such cases, and while a <nav> element can be used in such cases, it is usually unnecessary. Still not sure I should use it in the footer, as I described in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You should use both nav and ul tags to achieve this.

```
<nav>
    <h1>Title of Column 1</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>link11</li>
        <li>link12</li>
        <li>link13</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Beware that the H1 tag isn't that correct, as it downgrades the SEO power of the ACTUAL title of the page. I think a H2 would be the appropriate maximum level, while reserving the H1 for the "title".

Comment: @e-sushi Absolutely not. If your doctype is set to HTML5, there's no problem to use multiple <header> or <h1> tags. See this video by Matt Cuts: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIn5qJKU8VM. Did you downvote my answer for that reason ?

Comment: Wrong call. I didn't down-vote anything here (yet). Btw: remember that Matt is only a Google employee and that there are more search engines out there besides Google. Remind yourself of the fact that Google doesn't have the final call on the STILL UNDER DEVELOPMENT html5 standards. I don't regard Matt to be a big voice when it comes to standards that are in "draft" modus. I thing relying on the fact that every search engine out there understands html5-tags like Google is a bit of a "hazard". That is, unless the website owner doesn't care about 1000+ alternate engines and directories.

Comment: Matt Cutts wouldn't have posted a video under the account "GoogleWebmasterHelp" if he wasn't sure that using multiple <h1> tags was definitively not a problem. SEO experts doesn't either see any problem with that: https://www.google.com/search?q=multiple%20h1%20site:seomoz.org And even though HTML5 is still under development, most of search engines already recognize page sectioning (nav, header, article, etc.).

Comment: You are aware that all he says is that "for Google, it's no problem", aren't you? As said, there are other engines than Google and I am absolutely sure that Matt has no insight in - for example - Bing's backend. Anyway, this is turning into an off-topic discussion and I think it's time to remind you that stackoverflow is not a discussion forum. Therefore, I'll end it here in favor of the community.

Comment: You've missed the part where I talked about the fact that major search engines recognize page sectioning (and thus multiple h1 tags) and that SEO experts don't see nothing wrong with that. Please, let me also remind you that arguing does not necessarily imply that we're either off-topic or on a discussion board.

Comment: Since you're new here: "Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat." http://stackoverflow.com/faq/#dontask Cya there.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it is better to use a list and make via css the list-style-type of the ul none.